# How can I get the same strstream functionality now that's deprecated?

Tags: c++

I use to write code like this:

```
void fun(char *buff, unsigned size)
{
    std::strstream str(buff, size);
    str << "hello world: " << 5;
}
```

so I can use stream output over an arbitrary buffer. I've found this technique both efficient (no allocations) and useful (streams!). Now that std::strstream is deprecated, how can I get the same speed+flexibility that I can get with this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library doesn't provide that functionality. However, Boost does with its generic streams and array sources/sinks.

[Boost Generic Stream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/generic_streams.html)
[Boost Array Devices](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/array.html)

```
char buff[size];
boost::stream<boost::array_sink> out(buff, size);
out << "Hello, world!";
```

(Code untested)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
#include <sstream>
std::stringstream str;
str << "hello world: " << 5;
```

Edit: Sorry, I think I over simplified your question.  That functionality is one of the things removed when changing to sstream.  Here is something similar (I think this works...):

```
#include <sstream>
void fun(char *buff, unsigned size)
{
    std::stringstream str;
    str << "hello world: " << 5;
    memcpy(buff, str.str().c_str(), size);
}
```

Comment: I think the poster asked for a way of handling the memory buffer himself.

Comment: std::stringstream allocates as you write to it. He wants to supply a fixed size pre-allocated buffer.

Comment: @Mattias @Peter: Ah, I was simply thinking he missed the switch from strstream to stringstream.  I'll make an update.

Comment: This is also not what he's looking for, and defeats the purpose. In the OP code, `strstream` will *not* do any allocation, because it's using the buffer provided. Yours will.

Comment: @GMan: Yes I understand that, but I was trying to show how to achieve the same effect of filling a buffer using sstream without another library.  I agree it is not the same as OP's code and is not as efficient.

Comment: stringstream allocates, and then we need a copy. efficiency is lost there.

Answer (score -1):

> Now that std::strstream is deprecated,
>   how can I get the same
>   speed+flexibility that I can get with
>   this code?

I think it was deprecated for a reason. I had numerous portability problems in past when dealing with case of stream reaching the end of the buffer. Lack of the unity probably triggered the deprecation in favor std::string using version.

Otherwise, it amuses me that you mention "speed" in context of iostreams and the "<<" operators. I did bunch of tests in past and iostreams simply cannot catch up with good ol' snprintf(). Making a function call for every element - the effect of "<<" operators - is taxing anyhow you look at it and would be always slower. That's the cost of strict type checks.

Comment: Not if the functions called are inlined, test your code with full optimizations (-O2, -fast, etc.)

Comment: "_That's the cost of strict type checks._" Nonsense.

Comment: On the other hand, `printf` has to parse the format string. So this is no way obvious. Indeed, for some implementations the `iostream`s are just as fast, and those that are slow (MSVC) are slow for another reason: they are implemented on top of `printf`.